# Django Facebook Login Authentication

Tags: python, django, facebook

I had an application that was using Facebook to login and authenticate. However from May onwards something happen and now users when trying to go to the site they are getting this error message.

[image]

```
import os
from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = ''

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'paymentlist',
    'bootstrap_datepicker_plus',
    'bootstrap4',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsPostCsrfMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django_user_agents.middleware.UserAgentMiddleware',
]


ROOT_URLCONF = 'paymesite.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'microsoft_auth.context_processors.microsoft',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = ''


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases
#
# DATABASES = {
#     'default': {
#         'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
#         'NAME': str(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "db.sqlite3")),
#     }
# }

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': '',
        'NAME': ,
        'USER': ,
        'PASSWORD': ,
        'HOST': ,
        'PORT': ,
    }
}
LOGIN_URL = "/login/"

ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
SOCIALACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED  = True
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
ACCOUNT_LOGOUT_ON_GET = True
ACCOUNT_DEFAULT_HTTP_PROTOCOL = "https"
DEFAULT_HTTP_PROTOCOL = "https"
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')



AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

# Cache backend is optional, but recommended to speed up user agent parsing
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache',
        'LOCATION': '127.0.0.1:11211',
    }
}

# Name of cache backend to cache user agents. If it not specified default
# cache alias will be used. Set to `None` to disable caching.
USER_AGENTS_CACHE = 'default'


#New Autehnication for Facebook

SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    'facebook': {
        'METHOD': 'oauth2',
        'SCOPE': ['email', 'public_profile'],
        'AUTH_PARAMS': {'auth_type': 'reauthenticate'},
        'INIT_PARAMS': {'cookie': True},
        'FIELDS': [
            'id',
            'email',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'middle_name',
            'name',
            'name_format',
            'picture',
            'short_name'
        ],
        'EXCHANGE_TOKEN': True,
        'VERIFIED_EMAIL': False,
        'LOCALE_FUNC': lambda request: 'en-US',
    }
}

SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_API_VERSION = '2.11'

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    "django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend",
    'microsoft_auth.backends.MicrosoftAuthenticationBackend',
    "allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend",
)



# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True



# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/




#STATICFILES_DIRS = ( os.path.join('static'), )
#STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')

AZURE_ACCOUNT_NAME = os.environ.get('AZURE_ACCOUNT_NAME', '')
AZURE_ACCOUNT_KEY = os.environ.get('AZURE_ACCOUNT_KEY', '')
AZURE_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = os.environ.get('AZURE_CUSTOM_DOMAIN', '')
AZURE_LOCATION = os.environ.get('AZURE_LOCATION', '')
AZURE_CONTAINER = os.environ.get('AZURE_CONTAINER', '')
STATIC_CONTAINER = os.environ.get('STATIC_CONTAINER', '')
MEDIA_URL = f'https://{AZURE_CUSTOM_DOMAIN}/{AZURE_LOCATION}/'
STATIC_URL = f'https://{AZURE_CUSTOM_DOMAIN}/{AZURE_LOCATION}/'

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.azure_storage.AzureStorage'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'paymesite.custom_azure.PublicAzureStorage'

#STATIC_URL = '/static/'
#STATIC_ROOT = "/home/site/wwwroot/static/"
#STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')
#STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join('static'), )

THUMBNAIL_DEFAULT_STORAGE = DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE

SITE_ID = 1
```

This is the settings file for this application. Not sure what I'm doing wrong and if I can continue using Facebook authentication without having the Facebook business account validated. The only information I need to retrieve from Facebook is the image, id, email, first name, last name, full name, short name